# Can a Hydraulic clutch be adjusted?

Tags: clutch, mazda

The biting point on my Mazda 2's clutch is very, very short and the car is uncomfortable to drive. Car is still under warranty, but the mechanic advised that it could not be adjusted and all Mazda 2 are like that. Do you guys know anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

Some makes can be adjusted through means of an adjusting nut on the master cylinder pushrod.  Not familiar with Mazda though.  Best bet is to grab a factory manual and look for a procedure.  Or if you're not afraid to maybe make the car undriveable, you could stick your head under the dash and start looking at the pushrod.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue that cannot be adjusted away. I used to have a 1989 Opel Vectra that had a biting point that was very long. The clutch was cable-operated and adjustable. On the other hand, on my newer 2011 Toyota Yaris the biting point was very short, so short that I occasionally stalled the engine, because I was used to the long biting point on the old 1989 Opel Vectra.

I think Toyota wanted the clutch to be very precise and therefore designed a system with short biting point.

Clutches on different cars just feel different. When I had the 1989 Opel Vectra, I also drove occasionally a VW Passat that just had a different feel in the clutch.

You will probably get used to the short biting point. So did I. The adjustment, if possible, would only move the biting point, not make it shorter or longer.